# Stripe Create Usage Record Error - Timestamp must be before the subscription's current period end time - Date.now()?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a stripe usage record for a customer on a metered plan.

When I'm using timestamp Date.now() in my request. The error I'm receiving is

> "Cannot create the usage record with this timestamp because timestamps must be before the subscription's current period end time"

This seems self-explanatory. But given the subscription's current period end time isn't for another 14 days, how can Date.now() not be before this.

```
        await stripe.usageRecords.create(
            'si_EwzQ....',
            {
                quantity: 2,
                timestamp: Date.now(),
                action: 'set'
            }
        )
```

Is this because the current subscription period is a trial? Or have I misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stripe is using a slightly different timestamp here. It's the number of seconds. You must divide it by 1000.

1. So `Date.now() / 1000` shall work.
2. However, Stripe APIs expects a whole number so `Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000)` or `(Date.now() / 1000).toFixed(0)` should work. (@William's comment, verified)

Comment: This still breaks if the resulting number has decimals, e.g. `1570202647.927`. To avoid this just do `Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000)`

Answer (score 2):

Node.JS uses millisecond timescales, so you are saying the current time is 1000 times more seconds than it currently is.

Just do this first `var currentTimestamp = Date.now()/1000`

Comment: The above will give the result in decimal format, so you can use Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000)` instead as Stripe uses a different format (without decimals).